# How do I get a top-level site list to cascade down to be accessible in a subsite?

Tags: list, 2007

I made a list on the top level site called **Years**. It is just a list of years for tagging documents with. I want this list to trickle down and be accessible within the sub sites. What do I need to do?

Comment: How do you intend to "tag" documents with a site?

Comment: Maybe tag is the wrong word? I want "Years" as a column for my documents in sub sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Here`](http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2009/04/using-site-columns-to-reuse-data.html) is an article I wrote awhile back showing how to use Site Columns to reuse values in a sub-site.

Comment: Thanks. I've done that before but for some reason I missed it as I kept trying to create a new column - completely ignoring the other option